# php-regex spell out numbers for units of time

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regular expression.
I want to spell out the numbers less than 10 which are not units of measurement(cm,mm,m,etc).
I tried this..

```
<?php
//spell out the numbers less than 10 which are not units of time
$match="5 feet";
if(preg_match('/(\d+)\s((?i)(?:j|kg|mm|cm|km|cu|ft|nm|khz|mhz|w|kw|sq|gb|kb|ghz|thz/',$match))
{
echo $match;
}
else
{
$replacement='$1 $2';
$x=preg_replace('/(\d+)\s((?i)(?:j|kg|mm|cm|km|cu|ft|nm|khz|mhz|w|kw|sq|gb|kb|ghz|thz))/',$replacement,$match);
}
echo convert($x);
function convert($string)
{
$spell = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
$num = range(0, 9);
return str_replace($num, $spell, $string);
}
?>
```

It is working for specified units.IS there any better way for doing this.I also want to spell out names for all units.

Sample Output:

```
Input: 5 cm 5 mm
Output: 5 cm 5 mm
Input: 5 car 5 mm
Output: five car 5 mm
```

Comment: Your question does not seem fully clear to me. Could you possible add some sample input and output?

Comment: I assume you mean units of length or something else? (cm, mm, etc are length not time)

Comment: sorry it should be any unit.

Comment: Define any unit please

Comment: @ling.s  for unit of measurement it should not go to convert() function.other than tat it should go to the function convert().i get output for above program.iam looking for better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ling.s says an array is the correct way to go here, but you can use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) to greatly simplify the code. To do that you need to search for numbers that are *not* followed by a measurement, this uses '(?!...)' so this:

```
(/d+)(?!\s*(?:mm|kg))
```

Matches any numbers not followed by 'mm', the '?:' tells the system not to return the mm/kg as a match even if it's in parenthesis. If you have an array of units it's easy to get the internal reg exp part with `implode($units, "|")`. You can put all of that together to get a regex that only matches numbers not followed by measurements.

Now you can change your convert function slightly so it's compatible as a callback to `preg_replace_callback`, all the needs is to accept an array where the first element is the complete match:

```
function convert($matches)
{    
    $spell = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
    $num = range(0, 9);
    return str_replace($num, $spell, $matches[0]);
}
```

This will be called for each match and replace that match with the returned string, the rest of the code is:

```
function fix_numbers($match) { 
  $units = array("j","kg","mm","cm","km","cu","ft");

  // Lookahead for unit match 
  $regex = "/(\d+)(?!\s*(?:".implode($units, "|")."))/";

  return preg_replace_callback($regex, "convert", $match); 
}
```

Test code:

```
echo fix_numbers("5 feet 6 mm 3 trees") . "\n";
echo fix_numbers("5 cm 5 mm") . "\n";
echo fix_numbers("5 car 5 mm") . "\n";
```

*Output:*

```
five feet 6 mm three trees
5 cm 5 mm
five car 5 mm
```

Now, there's still a potential issue -- for a unit like 'cu' it's also going to match text like 'cube' so you may want to search for a space *after* the unit. But that complicates the match of the last one. This really depends on what your input is.

Also, your convert function is limited, there are plenty of other options out there if you want to replace that with a more fully functional version (i.e. here: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of allowed units, and then use your pattern.

Try something like

```
$units = array("kg", "mm", "cm", "km");
preg_match(....);
```